# Call own, non-overridden method

Tags: java, inheritance

Say I have this code (not actually my code, but easier to understand):

```
public class A {
    private int i1, i2;

    protected int getSum() {
        return i1 + i2;
    }

    protected int getSumTimes10() {
        return getSum() * 10;
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    protected int getSum() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

public class C extends B {

    public void doSomething() {
        // cannot call getSum();
        System.out.println(getSumTimes10());
    }
}
```

I overrive `getSum()` in `B` so that any class that `extends B` cannot call it. However, I do need it in `B` itself.

Calling `doSomething()` on any `C` will cause an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

How can I make `A` use its own `getSum()` and not the overridden one so that I don't have to write the method twice?

Comment: Why do you have "getSum" to begin with where other classes override it? This design seems flawed. Maybe make "getSumPrivate" and use that one, then have "getSum" that gets overridden that calls getSumPrivate.

Comment: Hi @matt, yes, it is flawed. I am currently using a second method, but it makes the thing quite complicated and I still have a method which is overridden with an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Isn't there any better approach?

Comment: To clarify, `A` does use its own `getSum()`, because it doesn't know about `B` or `C`. But `C` will use the reference that it knows about, which is from `B`. If you don't want `C` to run into the exception, `C` would need to extend from `A` directly.

Comment: @Scott `C` does need some other methods from `B`.

Comment: @EskandarAbedini I want to call the method from class `A` in class `B`, not from a grandparent method.

Comment: Maybe you have simplified it too much because I cannot understand why you need A's implementation of `getSumTimes10` to use a method `getSum` than can be overridden.

Comment: @matt Your right, it makes more sense to put it in B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language itself doesn't give you any specific tools to be able to do that. While there exists `super.someMethod()` to invoke a parent's implementation, there is no equivalent way to invoke a method which has the semantics that you're describing.

In the rare cases I've seen this be a desirable design choice, the usual workaround is to introduce a new method, possibly with some arbitrary prefix to make the name distinct, like `do`.

```
public class A {
    private int i1, i2;

    protected int getSum() {
        return doGetSum(); // delegate to non-overrideable version
    }

    protected int getSumTimes10() {
        return doGetSum() * 10; // delegate to non-overrideable version
    }
    
    private int doGetSum() {
        return i1 + i2;
    }
}
```

Your base class can rely on the `do___` version in cases where the overridden version would be undesirable and you never have to duplicate the implementation.

Comment: I already did it that way, I just didn't like it because I've got multiple methods like this. The alternative would be to have duplicate code in all direct subclasses of A, which isn't what I want either.

Comment: @Cactusroot As far as I know, those are the 2 options. I would favour the non-duplicating one too.